# Finding functional forms and state space in a state-space model

Tags: regression, time-series, multivariate-analysis, state-space-models, exploratory-data-analysis

Let's say that we have a time series:
$$\{y_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1}, y_i \in \mathcal{Y} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m, m \in \mathbb{N}_1$$
that we would like to model with some sort of state-space model:
$$x_i = f(x_{i-1}, i) + \nu_i$$
$$y_i = g(x_i, i) + \epsilon_i$$
where $\nu_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ are (i.i.d?) noise terms.

In practice, how do we even begin to think about suitable functional forms for $f$ and $g$, what the $x_i$'s are going to look like, or the distributions of $\nu_i$ or $\epsilon_i$?

Would a natural approach be to do some sort of state-space reconstruction with lags of $y_i$, e.g. letting $x_i := (y_{i-1}, y_i)$ and then trying to do some sort of multiple/multivariate regression analysis to derive a suitable form for $f$ and then have $g$ simply be the function that returns the last $y$-component of $x_i$? although that seems hard for me to graphically visualize beyond the case of $m=1$ and perhaps $m=2$.